# getting javascript error object required

Tags: php, javascript

Iam getting offsetwidth of an div tag. Below is code.

```
 <body>
  <div id="marqueeborder" onmouseover="pxptick=0" onmouseout="pxptick=scrollspeed">
<div id="marqueecontent">


<?php

    // Original script by Walter Heitman Jr, first published on http://techblog.shanock.com

    // List your stocks here, separated by commas, no spaces, in the order you want them displayed:
    $stocks = "idt,iye,mill,pwer,spy,f,msft,x,sbux,sne,ge,dow,t";

    // Function to copy a stock quote CSV from Yahoo to the local cache. CSV contains symbol, price, and change
    function upsfile($stock) { copy("http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=$stock&f=sl1c1&e=.csv","stockcache/".$stock.".csv"); }

    foreach ( explode(",", $stocks) as $stock ) {

        // Where the stock quote info file should be...
        $local_file = "stockcache/".$stock.".csv";

        // ...if it exists. If not, download it.
        if (!file_exists($local_file)) { upsfile($stock); }
        // Else,If it's out-of-date by 15 mins (900 seconds) or more, update it.
        elseif (filemtime($local_file) <= (time() - 900)) { upsfile($stock); }

        // Open the file, load our values into an array...
        $local_file = fopen ("stockcache/".$stock.".csv","r");
        $stock_info = fgetcsv ($local_file, 1000, ",");

        // ...format, and output them. I made the symbols into links to Yahoo's stock pages.
        echo "<span class=\"stockbox\"><a href=\"http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=".$stock_info[0]."\">".$stock_info[0]."</a> ".sprintf("%.2f",$stock_info[1])." <span style=\"";
        // Green prices for up, red for down
        if ($stock_info[2]>=0) { echo "color: #009900;\">&uarr;";   }
        elseif ($stock_info[2]<0) { echo "color: #ff0000;\">&darr;"; }
        echo sprintf("%.2f",abs($stock_info[2]))."</span></span>\n";
        // Done!
        fclose($local_file); 
    }
?>
<span class="stockbox" style="font-size:0.6em">Quotes from <a href="http://finance.yahoo.com/">Yahoo Finance</a></span>

</div>
</div>
 </body>
```

below is the javascript function which will be called onlaod of the page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    // Original script by Walter Heitman Jr, first published on http://techblog.shanock.com

    // Set an initial scroll speed. This equates to the number of pixels shifted per tick
    var scrollspeed=2;
    var pxptick=scrollspeed;

    function startmarquee(){
        alert("hi");
        // Make a shortcut referencing our div with the content we want to scroll
        var marqueediv=document.getElementById("marqueecontent");
        alert("marqueediv"+marqueediv);
        alert("hi"+marqueediv.innerHTML);

        // Get the total width of our available scroll area
        var marqueewidth=document.getElementById("marqueeborder").offsetWidth;
        alert("marqueewidth"+marqueewidth);
        // Get the width of the content we want to scroll
        var contentwidth=marqueediv.offsetWidth;
        alert("contentwidth"+contentwidth);
        // Start the ticker at 50 milliseconds per tick, adjust this to suit your preferences
        // Be warned, setting this lower has heavy impact on client-side CPU usage. Be gentle.
        var lefttime=setInterval("scrollmarquee()",50);
        alert("lefttime"+lefttime);
    }

    function scrollmarquee(){
        // Check position of the div, then shift it left by the set amount of pixels.
        if (parseInt(marqueediv.style.left)>(contentwidth*(-1)))
            marqueediv.style.left=parseInt(marqueediv.style.left)-pxptick+"px";
        // If it's at the end, move it back to the right.
        else
            marqueediv.style.left=parseInt(marqueewidth)+"px";
    }

    window.onload=startmarquee();

</script>
```

when iam running the above code on server, iam getting javascript error as "object required" at line 46 also the alert("marqueediv"+marqueediv); is "marqueedivnull" after that alert iam getting the javascript error.

Here my question is, did the div tag is not getting recognized?why?
so that only it is getting as null object, how can i resolved this?

Thanks.

Comment: `window.onload=startmarquee();` this calls the startmarquee function immediately and set the return value to `window.onload`. You need to pass reference of function. Do this, `window.onload = startmarquee`. Also, I would suggest you to use `console.log` in place of alerts. That will help to make your js programming better :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling `startmarquee` immediately and trying to assign its return value (`undefined`) to `window.onload`.

Presumably the script appears in the `<head>` and this the div does not exist at the time you run it.

Assign the function to `onload`, not its return value.

```
window.onload=startmarquee;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could copy the script and put it before the body closing tag and remove `window.onload=startmarquee();` thus making sure all elements have been loaded and accessible

Just like @Quentin said, that element with the id might not have been loaded into the DOM when you referenced it